# Firebase real-time-database structure doubts

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

I am new to nosql and firebase real-time-database and I have a question about the structure of database.

1,

For example if I structured my database in this way

```
user-
     user1-
           info-
                followers-
                           user2
                           user3
                           user4
           posts-
                 ...
```

If i access the follower information user using :

`ref.child('users').child('user1').child('info').child('followers')`

firebase will only download the child nodes of follwers right? It will not download the other nodes to the user, is that correct?

2,

If I retrieve data using :

`ref.queryOrdered(byChild:"index").queryStarting(atValue:start).queryEnding(atValue: end)`

Only data between the starting index and the end index will be downloaded to the user end right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes
2. Yes. That's how it's defined according the documentation for [queryStarting()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebasedatabase/api/reference/Classes/FIRDatabaseQuery#-querystartingatvalue) and [queryEnding()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebasedatabase/api/reference/Classes/FIRDatabaseQuery#-queryendingatvalue).  Note that the start and end values are **inclusive**, meaning any records with values that are equal to the start and end values will be part of the results.